# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { when trying to run protractor test

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, protractor, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to run a very simple set of protractor tests, however, when i run the "yarn e2e" command, i got the following error:

```
import { browser } from "protractor";
   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

The code in protractor-config.ts where the error occurs is:

```
import { browser } from "protractor";

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 20000,

  specs: ['./spec/spec.ts'],

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 720000
  },

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
  },

  directConnect: true,

  framework: 'jasmine',

  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

  onPrepare: function () {
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
  }
}
```

What i've tried:

- Changing

> import { browser } from "protractor";

to

> const browser = require('protractor');

- Changing "target": "es5" to es6 in my tsconfig.json

[image: tsconfig.json]

But non of this options made any difference!

Anyone has any idea on what can this be? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal i got "Unexpected identifier 'browser' " error.

Comment: Mixing `import` and `require` syntax makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your protractor.config.js should contain :

```
require('ts-node').register({
    project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json' // if you have one
});
```

This part is the one telling protractor how to handle typescript. This part of code is from angular-cli, so I suggest you to create a new angular app from scratch with `ng new myapp` and compare the config (protractor is working by default)

Comment: What if i don't have a tsconfig.e2e.json ?

Comment: comment that line out ?

Comment: Still, the same error occurs, what would be the purpose of that line?

Comment: How could protractor know to execute typescript if you don't tell him ? it's the `require('ts-node')` that is important

Comment: I added that line in protractor-config, the error stops showing in there, but instead, the same error is showing now in my specs files, even if i add that line there too

Comment: I suggest you to create a new angular app from scratch with `ng new myapp` and compare the config (protractor is working by default)

Comment: If you post the last question as an answer, i will close this thread!
Thanks a lot, by copying the configuration of a newly generated angular/cli app, i've managed to get my tests running!